# Stardock: get get individual application installers?

Tags: windows, installer, stardock, impulse

I bought a stardock subscription more or less a year ago, and i'd rather not use their Impulse client. Is there any way to get installers for the individual applications?

Comment: May I ask why you would rather not ? Something not working with it ?

Comment: I never really liked steam/impulse/gametap/etc. type installation as you don't really get to control the programs/games, you can only install them if the service is running. Plus if you don't happen to have internet access on a computer you can't install it from there.

Comment: Impulse is like SDCentral, it's only used for the time of downloading, you don't need to use it later. Eventually, for the "no internet while installing", you can download on a computer with internet, make a backup in Impulse, and install on other computer from backup.

Comment: In general, Impulse is only a platform to download, install, and notify you about updates (and install them easily). It doesn't have anything to do in the program itself, after installing. (As opposed to Steam, etc, where the client needs to be open to use the programs you bought, for example). Note: I don't try to defend especially Stardock, I'm only explaining how this works, to clarify eventually some misunderstanding about the way it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they switched to the Impulse client, everything from Stardock comes from it. It replaces the SDCentral which was used before.

All software bought from Stardock must be downloaded using Impulse. There is an exception for one or two games, if I remember (but I can't find the link back), which have a direct download link from their site, under the condition you have an Impulse account already.

<strike>I'll try to find back this link, but I doubt it concerns other products as well.</strike>

**Edit:** I found back the [little article](http://frogboy.impulsedriven.net/article/358061/Impulse_Anywhere), this is still a "beta" service, so not really advertised. The name of this service is "[Impulse Anywhere](http://anywhere.impulsedriven.com/)", and according to the article, it concerns only applications which are protected by "[Goo](http://www.stardock.com/about/newsitem.asp?id=1214)" (their answer to DRM).

I know it applies to games, but I'm not sure about Desktop applications (I don't own any from them). Although, I found [this answer](http://forums.stardock.com/356125/page/1/#2260568) in their forums, which seems to indicate it works for their applications, not only games. I can only recommend you to check by yourself, since I cannot myself.

---

Answer to comment : I'm sorry but I don't fully understand your issue. I never used their subscriptions, so I don't really know how they work. But why is that a problem with trying this "Impulse Anywhere" ?

Comment: This confuses me then. How do i get access to programs after my year is up? the page specifically said that i don't have to keep subscribing and i still get to keep the software i bought.

Comment: I bought object desktop, which doesnt have DRM to my knowledge. Thus i don't think IMpulse Anywhere will work.

Comment: Object Desktop is from Stardock directly, as opposed to third party games. According to them, it might work, so give it a try.

Comment: I'll go ahead and try that.